# Trim Related Products Title Length - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I currently have an issue with trimming the length of the product title in the "Related Products" section of my single product page.

I have set up a custom hook pointing to a custom template for this. The only problem is that it isn't trimming any of it - it is still printing the whole title.

I have tried to use get_the_title() and it doesn't print anything to screen, so in the code below I have tried to pass the title as a string and not an array.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php $title = the_title('<h3 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h3>'); 

    $text = wp_trim_words($title, 2, '...')

?>
<?php echo $text; ?>
```

Thanks in advance
Regards
Michael

Comment: trim by only 2 length ? the_title() function doesn't return a value, it prints. You need to use get_the_title() function. So, atleast read the function signature before using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_title()` will be auto print as you don't need to echo it.

You need to use filter for title as the following in functions.php,

```
function trim_title( $title ) {

  $title = wp_trim_words( $title , 40, '...' );

  return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'trim_title', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Worked a treat. Now to have it only trim titles in the related products and not for the product itself. :)

Comment: To change the related product titles only , go to single-product/related.php  and change from there , or use this hook : http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title/ , :)

Comment: Took a while, but realised after inserting `add_filter( 'the_title', 'trim_title', 2, 1 );` after if($related_products) in related.php it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work in up-sells.php even if it's almost the same as related.php , instead of this whole `function trim_title( $title )` in both files after `$post_object = get_post( $upsell->get_id() );` (or $related_product) I added `$post_object->post_title = substr( $post_object->post_title, 0, 50) . '…';`  and it works. It limits to 50 characters, you can change.